# Data not pulls properly for below query

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Update Tbl_PPACA_Import set
    LASTNAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LASTNAME)),
    FIRSTNAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(A.FIRSTNAME)),
    LEVEL1CODE = LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(A.LEVEL1CODE,ISNULL((
                    SELECT TOP 1 Location_Code
                    FROM Tbl_Location 
                    WHERE Employer_Id=@Employer_Id 
                    AND Location like '%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL1DESCRIPTION))+'%' ),
    LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL1DESCRIPTION)))))),
    LEVEL1DESCRIPTION = LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(A.LEVEL1DESCRIPTION,A.LEVEL1CODE))),
    LEVEL2CODE=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL2CODE)),
    LEVEL2DESCRIPTION=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL2DESCRIPTION)),
    LEVEL3CODE=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL3CODE)),
    LEVEL3DESCRIPTION=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL3DESCRIPTION)),
    LEVEL4CODE=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL4CODE)),
    LEVEL4DESCRIPTION=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL4DESCRIPTION)),
    LEVEL5CODE=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL5CODE)),
    LEVEL5DESCRIPTION=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.LEVEL5DESCRIPTION)),
    UNIONCODE=LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UNIONCODE)),
    SSN=LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(A.SSN,'-',''))),
    -- The following line is the line in question
    DATEOFHIRE=(select top 1  ISNULL(DOHIRE,cast('01-01-1900' as date))
                    from tbl_basicinfo
                    where ssn=a.ssn
                    and employer_Id=a.employeriD)       
    from Tbl_PPACA_Import A
```

Note:: Last line of this query does not pulling DOHIRE column values from tbl_basicinfo table.. other part of this query works perfectly but last line does not pulls DOHIRE.

Comment: Are you sure, that your table `tbl_basicinfo` has got data for the given `WHERE`-clause? Did you try to call only the inner select to check this?

Comment: All the other query works properly but Hiredate is not pulling fro tbl_basicinfo i tried above line code but not working for me.

Comment: Hi Zafar, I'm curious... could you solve this problem?

Comment: No just an empty dateofhire as before

Comment: If you get not data with the approach I describe in my answer I promise you, that there is not fitting data at all. Please check `tbl_basicinfo` manually. Are you querying the right db?

Comment: i checked tbl_basicinfo very carefully sir but it's not working sir

Comment: What happens if you set a fix date there? Just use `DATEOFHIRE=GETDATE()` (but make sure you do not destroy real data!) What I wrote in my answer should still be true: If the sub-select returns at least one row the `ISNULL()` makes sure, that there is at least the default date written...

Comment: Question: Do you mean `NULL`, when you speak of "empty dateofhire as before" ?

Comment: yes null not empty sorry for that sir

Comment: The only chance to get a NULL value, when you provide a value which gets a default in case of NULL is  when there is **no data at all**. Did you try to set a fix date?

Comment: Now my problem is fixed sir
Thank you @Shnugo

Comment: I'm glad to read this!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746127/error-in-sql-store-procedure.
@shnugo can you please help me in above question

Comment: Please find my answer there, hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pick out the part which seems not to work properly:

```
 DATEOFHIRE=(select top 1  ISNULL(DOHIRE,cast('01-01-1900' as date))
                    from tbl_basicinfo
                    where ssn=a.ssn
                    and employer_Id=a.employeriD)
```

As you are using `ISNULL` there should be an result in any case - unless there is no data at all!

Try the following: Comment the `WHERE` part away (double minus, be aware of the final bracket!)

```
 DATEOFHIRE=(select top 1  ISNULL(DOHIRE,cast('01-01-1900' as date))
                    from tbl_basicinfo
                    --where ssn=a.ssn
                    --and employer_Id=a.employeriD
             )
```

You will not get the correct date, but there will be a date. Am I correct?

If yes, I think, that there is no data which fits to `ssn=a.ssn and employer_Id=a.employeriD`