# Error in Sql store procedure

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Basicinfo(Employer_Id,Lname,Fname,UserName,Userpass,Location_Id,cc2,CC3,cc4,cc5,Dohire,Job_Status,ssn,Import_Emp_No,[Benefit_Terminate], [Show_Age], [Change_IP], [IsNewHired])
            SELECT M.Employer_Id,M.LASTNAME,M.FIRSTNAME,UPPER(LEFT(ISNULL(M.FIRSTNAME,'A'),1)+''+LEFT(ISNULL(M.LASTNAME,'C'),1))+CONVERT(VARCHAR,MaxImportEENumber+ROWNUM) [UserName],RIGHT(NEWID(),10) [UserPass],ISNULL(M.Location_Id,0)[Location_Id],M.Level2code,M.Level3code,M.LEVEL4Code,M.LEVEL5Code,M.DATEOFHIRE,
            1 [JobStatus],SSN,M.MaxImportEENumber+ROWNUM [ImportEmpNo],0 [Benefit_Terminate], 0[Show_Age],M.ChangeIP,1 [IsNewHired] from(
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FIRSTNAME]) AS ROWNUM,* FROM
            (
                    SELECT DISTINCT @Employer_Id [Employer_Id],PR.LASTNAME,PR.FIRSTNAME,(SELECT  MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Employee_Id,0) as BIGINT)) from Tbl_Basicinfo) [MaxImportEENumber],
                    (SELECT TOP 1 Location_Id from Tbl_Location where Location_Code=PR.LEVEL1CODE and Employer_Id=@Employer_Id and Location like '%'+PR.LEVEL1DESCRIPTION+'%')  [Location_Id],
                    (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL2Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL2Code,
                    (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL3Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL3Code,
                    (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL4Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL4Code,
                    (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL5Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL5Code,
                    (SELECT MIN(DATEOFHIRE) from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) DATEOFHIRE,1 Job_Status,PR.SSN,PR.ChangeIP

                        from Tbl_PPACA_Import PR
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_Basicinfo L ON L.ssn=PR.SSN and L.Employer_Id=PR.EmployerId
                        WHERE PR.EmployerId=@Employer_Id and L.SSN is null and ISNULL(PR.SSN,'') not like '' AND ISNUMERIC(PR.SSN)=1
                        and ISNULL(PR.PPE,DATEOFHIRE) =(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(PPE,DATEOFHIRE)) FROM Tbl_PPACA_Import I WHERE I.SSN=PR.SSN AND I.EmployerId=PR.EmployerId ) 

                    ) V
            ) M;
```

Note: Can some one help me I am receiving this error from above query:

> Error 515: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserName', table 'ppacahelper.dbo.Tbl_Basicinfo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. Line: 131 spImportPPACAREPORT

Any help will highly be apprecieted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add ISNULL to all the columns you are concatenating for username value:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_Basicinfo(Employer_Id,Lname,Fname,UserName,Userpass,Location_Id,cc2,CC3,cc4,cc5,Dohire,Job_Status,ssn,Import_Emp_No,[Benefit_Terminate], [Show_Age], [Change_IP], [IsNewHired])
        SELECT M.Employer_Id,M.LASTNAME,M.FIRSTNAME,UPPER(LEFT(ISNULL(M.FIRSTNAME,'A'),1)+''+LEFT(ISNULL(M.LASTNAME,'C'),1))+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ISNULL(MaxImportEENumber,0)+ISNULL(ROWNUM,0)) [UserName],RIGHT(NEWID(),10) [UserPass],ISNULL(M.Location_Id,0)[Location_Id],M.Level2code,M.Level3code,M.LEVEL4Code,M.LEVEL5Code,M.DATEOFHIRE,
        1 [JobStatus],SSN,M.MaxImportEENumber+ROWNUM [ImportEmpNo],0 [Benefit_Terminate], 0[Show_Age],M.ChangeIP,1 [IsNewHired] from(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FIRSTNAME]) AS ROWNUM,* FROM
        (
                SELECT DISTINCT @Employer_Id [Employer_Id],PR.LASTNAME,PR.FIRSTNAME,(SELECT  MAX(CAST(ISNULL(Employee_Id,0) as BIGINT)) from Tbl_Basicinfo) [MaxImportEENumber],
                (SELECT TOP 1 Location_Id from Tbl_Location where Location_Code=PR.LEVEL1CODE and Employer_Id=@Employer_Id and Location like '%'+PR.LEVEL1DESCRIPTION+'%')  [Location_Id],
                (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL2Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL2Code,
                (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL3Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL3Code,
                (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL4Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL4Code,
                (SELECT TOp 1 LEVEL5Code from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) LEVEL5Code,
                (SELECT MIN(DATEOFHIRE) from Tbl_PPACA_Import where ssn=PR.SSN and EmployerId=PR.EmployerId) DATEOFHIRE,1 Job_Status,PR.SSN,PR.ChangeIP

                    from Tbl_PPACA_Import PR
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_Basicinfo L ON L.ssn=PR.SSN and L.Employer_Id=PR.EmployerId
                    WHERE PR.EmployerId=@Employer_Id and L.SSN is null and ISNULL(PR.SSN,'') not like '' AND ISNUMERIC(PR.SSN)=1
                    and ISNULL(PR.PPE,DATEOFHIRE) =(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(PPE,DATEOFHIRE)) FROM Tbl_PPACA_Import I WHERE I.SSN=PR.SSN AND I.EmployerId=PR.EmployerId ) 

                ) V
        ) M;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this expression returns NULL:

```
UPPER(LEFT(ISNULL(M.FIRSTNAME,'A'),1)+''
+LEFT(ISNULL(M.LASTNAME,'C'),1))
+CONVERT(VARCHAR,MaxImportEENumber+ROWNUM)
```

The first part will not be NULL due to the `ISNULL` on `M.FIRSTNAME`
The second part will not be NULL due to the `ISNULL` on `M.LASTNAME`
So it must be the third part...

Either `MaxImportEENumber` or `ROWNUM` must be NULL...

Please check this...

You can easily define a default by writing

**Attention**: you probably want to change the `CONVERT(VARCHAR` to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(XY)`. Without specifying a length you won't get what you expect...

```
+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),MaxImportEENumber+ROWNUM),'YourDefaultValue')
```

Comment: Yes MaxImportEENumber is zero in my query.
Thank you @shnugo can i mail you personally so i will get my answer soon.so i can send you link of question which i pasted her to your email